# Index 4 beyond bounds for NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner in this field and I'm facing this problem which says :[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]:Index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]. Can't seem to find out error for this. Can any body help me in this regard? I'm attaching the code snippet for this...

```
NSMutableArray *my_arrUserinfo = [UserresponcePerser userdesc];
NSString *encryptAlgo=@"";
encryptAlgo = [encryptAlgo stringByAppendingString:[[my_arrUserinfo objectAtIndex:9]objectAtIndex:4]];
```

the UserresponcePerser is a perser which perses data elements from web service and stores it in the array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too localised because it is of no use to anyone. An array out of bounds error is too basic to be on SO.

Comment: This question and answer were useful to me. The error occurred at runtime in my situation, making debug hard. Had very little hints. This question confirmed a gut feeling.

Comment: "An array out of bounds error is too basic to be on SO" - Totally disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means your `[my_arrUserinfo objectAtIndex:9]` only has 3 items, but you try to visit the 4th object.

Comment: Please read the code. He is trying to access the fourth object from the array [my_arrUserinfo objectAtIndex:9] returns.

Comment: That's exactly what Fernando said. "[The array retuned by] [my_arrUserinfo objectAtIndex:9] only has 3 items, but you try to vibist the 4th object."

Answer (score 1):

It means there's no item for the index 4. The object index is counted starting from 0, so the fourth object would be at the index 3, the third would be 2, the second would be 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

check how many data your "my_arrUserinfo" contains. and for EACH object in "my_arrUserinfo" , check also the count of their data. in your error message, it seems like your object at index x is not reachable in your array content.

```
NSLog(@"count my_arrUserinfo = %d", [my_arrUserinfo count]);

for(int i = 0; i < [my_arrUserinfo count] i++){
    NSLog(@"count of objectAtIndex %d inside my_arrUserinfo = %d", i ,[[my_arrUserinfo objectAtIndex:i] count]);
}
```